# Should I remove a merely superficially relevant tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

There is [this question (*Get PyCharm to stop asking for Git*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798260/get-pycharm-to-stop-asking-for-git). It has a [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) tag but although it asks about git integration in PyCharm, git is hardly relevant.

Should I remove the [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) tag from such a question? In general, should I remove only superfically relevant tags from questions?

Comment: Why do you think it's superfluous?  If it were any other VCS integration with PyCharm, I'd think that the VCS in question would *somewhat* be relevant to the question.  If anything, the python tag *is* superfluous, since the question is talking about an IDE, not an actual Python script.

Comment: @Makoto Because he doesn't ask how to get it running or because he has problems with it, he wants to disable the reminder to integrate it. He doesn't even has git on his system.

Comment: Yet it relates to Git; not wanting Git is also a Git-related question, I would imagine.

Comment: @Makoto And that's what I'm asking. I'm quite familiar with git but not really with PyCharm and as such can't answer the question. On the other hand someone familiar with PyCharm but not with git could be perfectly capable of answering.

Comment: Personally I do feel that it's relevant.  PyCharm (and the rest of JetBrains products) have the ability to interact with a lot of VCS systems.  I'm very familiar with JetBrains' IDEs but less familiar with other VCSs such as Subversion, Mercurial, or Perforce - so I'd be at a loss on how to solve those, too.  The question is still asking about something related to the VCS anyway, so I do feel that the tag is relevant.

Comment: I would say remove it.  No knowledge or experience with Git will help you solve that problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it was svn or mercurial, would the question/answer change? Going by the answer, its probable that no.

Removing all references to "git" from the question, invalidates the answer given? Reading the question as "How to stop PyCharm from asking for a VCS?" and reading the answer again, specially this sentence: *"Under Project Settings, navigate to the **Version Control** submenu. From there, select "none" as **your VCS**."*; I would say that git isn't relevant to the question and therefore not what the question is about.

Just incidental. Tangential. Not *relevant*. So, I believe, yes, [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) can be removed of the question. You being an git expert, but not having any idea why are you seeing this question, is quite the indicative that maybe your [field of expertise isn't necessary](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283550/removing-the-less-tag-from-unix-questions-using-the-less-command-good-thing?rq=1#comment147717_283552), and hence the question is badly tagged. This apply [even if it's code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278014/792066) that you are removing.

Where this doesn't apply? Whenever you remove something and makes the question lose meaning.