# We need [less] no more

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

Right now the [less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less) is (mis)used for three different things:

- The all popular CSS preprocessor LESS.
- The opposite of more and command line tool `less`
- A gem called less-rails.

This should not be happening. And there's a simple way to fix it. Burning and blacklisting [less]. The other three tags more or less exist.

1. [less-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less-rails) through without excerpt, is immediately obvious what the questions should be about.
2. [lesscss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lesscss) existed, but was merged into [less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less) for some obscure motive (which seems counterproductive, since it makes the unambiguous tag, ambiguous)
3. and for the command, I'm thinking on using [less-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less-command) or [less-pager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less-pager) through is advisable to figure out if those questions are on topic or not (also, `less` isn't specific to *NIX environments, so [unix-less] is out).

Anyone has another suggestion?

Comment: I agree with the suggestion that there should be no ambiguity and support creation of specific tags for each. However, we need a methodical process which involves a migration of existing questions also because without it all that the users would see while creating questions is the old `less` tag and would simply tag them instead of the newly proposed tags. (*Note:* I am removing my comments on the SO question because they don't add any value to the question as it is.)

Comment: @Harry added "blacklisting", so the tag isn't created again.

Comment: It looks like you're just trying to push your personal flavors hiding them with pseudo-reasonable rationale. Do you really believe 96% of Less language Q&As marked as [less] are not enough to capture the tag? (i.e it's clearly a command-line tool should be pushed out. And [`less-rails`](https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails) is no more than just one of the hundreds Less tools out there to not be involved in the decision at all).

Comment: @seven-phases-max: See [Removing the \[less\] tag from UNIX questions using the “less” command. Good thing to do?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283550/removing-the-less-tag-from-unix-questions-using-the-less-command-good-thing) (which I linked before), someone knowing CSS captured the tag-wiki and other used that as justification for untagging (not even retagging to something else) all the pager questions. And now you want to use that as justification for doing so???

Comment: @seven-phases-max tags should be unambiguous, independently how popular or the proportion to which is applied. Is two out four points to take into account [to burn a tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/): "Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? **and is it unambiguous?**"; "Does it **mean the same thing** in all common contexts?" Less fails on both, it means: a term of quantity (in the general folk context), a framework on multitude of language, a preprocessor, a pager, and a gem.

Comment: @Deduplicator You complaining "someone has captured the tag" - Ok, maybe I'm missing something (since I'm only here since 2013). So *when* has this happened?

Comment: @seven-phases-max: Look at the question I linked and the tag-wiki for less, as well as the synonym.

Comment: @Deduplicator So I looked but can't find an answer to my question. *when* has this happened?

Comment: How about (for commandline `less`) [tag:less-terminal] or [tag:less-console]? And then (if and when this is approved) retagging the old questions. Finally, edit the now-empty 'less' tag wiki with a note linking to the other, new tags.

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4132)

Comment: OK, let me explain in details why I'm actually pissed of that in such extreme way. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/238623) it's already about Less CSS processor - please enlighten me was this tag already [less] - yes/no? A few months later someone added a remark about shell-less but then it was removed. Then four years later someone else also adds a remark about shell-less and now you guys find it to be enough to change a four years working tag? So if I'll add something about the Latin letter C to [c] you will do the same?

Comment: This is crazy "destroy the village to save it" territory. Whatever minor confusion might exist today, burning this tag isn't going to make it *better.*

Comment: @Shog9 actually I'm suggesting disambiguation.

Comment: @Braiam It would be so if you have not aready [started](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30104960/revisions) to edit the tags behind the scenes.

Comment: @seven-phases-max I was following [the previous discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283550/removing-the-less-tag-from-unix-questions-using-the-less-command-good-thing), nothing behind scenes.

Comment: @Shog9: If the synonym was reversed, there would no longer be reason for confusion.

Comment: @seven: Yes, the one who first added a tag-wiki disregarded how it was used. So what?

Comment: @Deduplicator So you are suggesting to "reverse" [tag:c] to [tag:c-by-kernighan-and-ritchie-of-78], are you?

Comment: @seven-phases-max: Ehm, sry, but that's completely off-the-wall.

Comment: This title is cool

Comment: @seven-phases-max not sure what you are getting at, both are the same question.

Comment: My mistake again: it's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049433 vs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049350.

Comment: @seven-phases-max check the revisions. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1049350/revisions has the less tag since 2009, while the [css related had it added in 2011](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1049433/revisions). The actual [oldest reference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16828/792066) to the less tool is from 2008, but at the time, the tag wasn't applied.

Comment: @Deduplicator be honest: do you have any evidence of someone other than Braiam being confused by this tag?

Comment: @Shog9 not just me, check the 50 newest questions with the tag. At position [13-14 you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30048985/subprocess-very-slow-when-calling-external-egrep-and-less) will find one which is not about the preprocessor.

Comment: And that confused... Who, exactly?

Comment: @Shog9 [that user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4865610/milos-kostic-veljkovic), [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/796443/salivan), [this another user](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283550/792066), me.

Comment: I don't see any use at all for a tag for the `less` command on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JonEricson lets start [closing those questions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1049350/revisions)?

Comment: @Braiam: That would be the [false dilemma fallacy](http://www.fallacyfiles.org/eitheror.html). I'd recommend reading up on [folksonomies](http://www.adammathes.com/academic/computer-mediated-communication/folksonomies.html) which is what tags are.

Comment: @Braiam, rather than cherry-picking your data points, can you provide evidence that the percent of users who can't figure out the `less` tag is higher than the percent of users who can't figure out other obvious things, like say markdown syntax. Picking out 10 or 20 posts out of thousands seems statistically insignificant to me.

Comment: @JonEricson lets see if I'm following you: my plan is that lesscss, less tool/command, and rails-less have their own tags, and that those tags are not confused. You say that a tag for the less command isn't needed on SO. I say "super". Lets close them, since you are suggesting they are off topic (I agree with you, if that's the case) and solve the problem for the other two concept. I'm right?

Comment: @JonEricson: Nice paper, thanks. But even skimming the paper makes it obvious that tags here aren't actually a folksonomy, at least as that paper uses the term: We have tag-wikis to give them precise and unambiguous meanings, synonyms to make sure there are no duplicate tags (which inherently means we get to decide which is the master, which makes it possible in some instances to make mistagging obviously wrong), and we have active correction of the contents tags by at least part of the community.

Comment: As with most things on this site, it's a hybrid approach, @Deduplicator. That said, most tags are applied *by ordinary people* - folks asking or editing questions. We don't have a dedicated group of taxonomists here to carefully create and apply tags, nor would such a thing be feasible. Therefore, tagging *must* take its lead from the terms that make sense to those using them; splitting hairs over potential ambiguities when in practice the majority of users understand full well what a tag means is a pointless waste of time and potentially harms future tagging.

Comment: No one is saying less (the command) is *off-topic*, @Braiam. Merely that, in practice, on-topic questions about it are exceedingly rare; those that require tagging moreso. Let's keep scope creep to a minimum.

Comment: @Shog9 then, if less doesn't deserve a tag how are we supposed to categorize them? I, for one, could be interested in knowing the nasty stuff I can do programmatically with less (the command) since I come from a sysadmin background rather than programmer, which tag should I look for?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, @Braiam, the less command is not commonly used programatically - it is, after all, intended as an interactive utility. If you can find evidence to the contrary, that would make a useful addition to the discussion here - but failing that, I'm not really convinced this even needs a tag.

Comment: @Shog9: Lots of tools want output paging but don't want to implement their own pager. Traditionally you do that by piping to `$PAGER` if it exists, `more` if it doesn't. Which, on most modern systems, means you're using `less` programmatically, if not directly. And sometimes you do want to pass along arguments (especially `-s`)… although you usually wouldn't want to pass anything that POSIX `more` doesn't specify.

Comment: @Shog9 I remember finding some questions about it [just now 
(now being about couple of hours)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1049350/792066). [This also](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30048985/792066). I'm sure you notice that the use of less could be replaced with any pager, but I still think the use of less is relevant.

Answer (score 20):

I see no evidence of real confusion or ambiguity here. Yes, less is also the name of a Unix command; that's mostly irrelevant here. IDE means something else in other contexts too, but the [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide) tag is still clear.

In the context of Stack Overflow, less refers to a language for generating CSS. We don't need awkward tags to clarify that; it's already obvious. Don't try to make the site uglier by pushing for some horrible name spacing scheme when it isn't necessary.

Please re-read [When to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) - particularly the bits where I recommend using the Related Tags sidebar to help identify the meaning of a tag:

[image]

Those are the related tags for [less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less). There's *nothing* about Unix there. Even if you expand the related tags and search the full list, it's clear that web development is far and away the most common use here. Yes, there's [ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) - but guess what, that's *still* related to the Less language, in this case the use of it with Rails. Just like the PHP tag relates to using Less with PHP.

You're not new to this. I *know* you've read that guide before - but even if you hadn't, there's a pop-up that links to it when you post a question here with the [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) tag. Starting this discussion without doing proper research on the tag you recommend burning is careless; starting to actually *retag* the questions without waiting for others to weigh in is down-right irresponsible. **Please do not do this again.**

Comment: I don't understand what's so bad about disambiguating something? I mean, what's there to lose here? Couple hours that we could be procrastinating? I only see gains.

Comment: @Braiam, don't rename `less` to `css-less` unless you're prepared to also remove `sass` and rename it to `css-sass`. Might as well go all in and rename `bootstrap` to `js-bootstrap` and `django` to `python-django` along with many many others.

Comment: Really? You don't see what harm comes from disallowing **the name everyone uses** in favor of your awkward synonym, just to avoid a mostly-hypothetical problem? Figure it out.

Comment: @zzzzBov is `sass` ambiguous? is `django` ambiguous? yes? Then by all means rename them, otherwise no. There are three things in three context sharing the tag, and it isn't [intermediately obvious](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256114/people-dont-read-the-tag-excerpts-because-we-dont-swat-them-into-their-faces)

Comment: @Braiam, the `less` description makes it immediately obvious and abundantly clear what the tag is used for. I don't consider it to be even remotely ambiguous.

Comment: @zzzzBov read my link, please? People don't read tag excerpts/wiki.

Comment: I think that depends on what you do as a programmer.  I'm personally at least 2-3 orders of magnitude more likely to ask about the less Unix command (or less as a mathematical concept) than less CSS.  Which is true for anyone who isn't a web programmer (the majority of us).

Comment: Irrelevant, @Gabe. Ask yourself, are you more likely to ask a question about the less command, *using the less tag*, than someone who works with the less preprocessor? (to date, [you haven't](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1631193+%5Bless%5D))

Comment: @shog9 yes, if I asked the question I would assume that's what the tag was for, because 99 percent of programmers have never heard of less-css. The idea that it would be for some tiny css tool is relatively ridiculous. So I would 100 percent tag any question I had about the less command line tool with less

Comment: That's not what I wrote, @Gabe. Here's the reality: in the (unlikely) scenario you'd ever ask a question about the less command on Stack Overflow, you'd use the less tag for it. Meanwhile, in the *daily* occurrence of someone asking a question about the less **programming language** on Stack Overflow, they would also use the less tag. So we have the *potential* for you to be confused in a scenario that stands a really good chance of never occurring, or the *guarantee* of someone else being confused in a scenario that happens constantly. You see where I'm going here?

Comment: @Shog9: Because you added those related tags, I did a quick search... and the less not lesscss questions don't have a unix tag or such: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1053707 http://stackoverflow.com/q/1254726 http://stackoverflow.com/q/2336745 http://stackoverflow.com/q/4229790 http://stackoverflow.com/q/6376360 (Something else: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3585443) Not saying whether those are good or not, that's not what I looked for. Only looked at the last 20 active questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=33&tab=active&q=%5bless%5d%20-css%20-lesscss%20is%3aq

Comment: See, *that's* the kind of research I'd hope to see before considering burnination, @Deduplicator! Keep going - so far, I'm seeing a [trivial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less+ubuntu) number of [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less+bash) in these related tags.

Comment: @Shog9 Actually, most of the questions tagged `less`+`ubuntu` are about installing the CSS pre-processor or running the command line version of it, `lessc`.

Comment: HA! Well, that's even less evidence of a significant use of less-the-command then, @this

Comment: It's difficult to find those less-questions which were untagged earlier, like http://stackoverflow.com/q/831681 Maybe there's a way with SEDE to compare past and current tags??? Looking for them at the moment...

Comment: Found a way to get all 174 questions which lost [less] prior to last data-dump: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/311349/find-formerly-tagged-questions?Tag=less Some were properly retagged, others only lost [less] or got (nearly) useless tags n exchange.

Comment: It definitely does not make sense for me to ditch the less command -- it is important for many programmers. It is the most used pager for `git`, `mercurial`, and other command line programs, which many many programmers use. Plus, it has [a lot of features that may produce questions](https://www.topbug.net/blog/2016/09/27/make-gnu-less-more-powerful/). It is no good to make such assumptions that people don't care about it.

Answer (score 9):

**Disclaimer:** I follow the [less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less) tag only because of its usage for questions about Less the CSS pre-processor and hence my views could be a bit biased even though I have tried my best not to be.

I can see that Shog9 and seven-phases-max have already provided their suggestions/views on this topic (and there seems to be a lot more people agreeing with Shog's views than those opposing). However I feel that I owe an explanation because I am the one who [rolled back your re-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30104960/revisions) (the trigger point for this question) and also clarify on my comment (which admittedly was posted hastily last night).

The reasons for rolling your edit back was:

- There was no prior community consensus on a switch from [less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less) to [less-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less-css). However, I understand your point that a *consensus was assumed to be in place* because there were no/less opposing views in the [previous thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283550/removing-the-less-tag-from-unix-questions-using-the-less-command-good-thing?lq=1) earlier.
- Starting to re-tag questions tagged with [less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less) to [less-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less-css) on one fine day without doing anything about the tag with the ambiguous name will only cause more confusions than solutions. For instance, the new tag will never show up on the auto suggested list of tags unless its popularity is higher than [less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less). Considering that [less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less) has around 4.25k questions, we are a long way away from achieving this.
- Users who don't know the system well would probably choose the tags displayed to them by default (read as [less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less)) and those that know the system would probably be confused and tag both the old and new ones because both indicate usage for Less CSS questions. Even if we do a mass migration of Less CSS questions to [less-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less-css), there is absolutely no guarantee that a new user wouldn't add [less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less) again unless it is blacklisted.

Considering the above points, if there was a consensus to move away, then the wise option would have been to remove [less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less) totally to avoid confusion before proceeding to re-tag.

---

Now coming to the burnination request itself, the following are the points that I understand should be considered before doing it:

- **Is the tag name ambiguous**? Yes, in my view **the name** is ambiguous because it could refer to a lot of things.
- **Has it caused any confusion to even warrant a discussion**? Probably yes, because there have been cases where UNIX (or Pager) Less questions have been tagged with [less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less) (irrespective of how minimal the actual count has been).
- **Can the same tag be used for two different things by combining them with another tag**? Not in this case because Less the CSS pre-processor and Less the UNIX command are completely different. There are some tags (like [linear-gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linear-gradient)) where this is possible because they can be used in combination with other more specific tags (like CSS or SVG etc). That is because a linear gradient probably has the same meaning in all those. **For Less Rails**, this model should be enough (that is, [ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) or [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) and [less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less))
- **Does the tag describe or attempt to describe its usage**? Yes, it did. Initially the tag excerpt and wiki specifically indicated the usage of this tag for Less the CSS pre-processor. Currently, it has a statement about Less the UNIX command which is causing a bit more confusion.

In an ideal scenario, I would still say that I prefer [less-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less-css), [less-pager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less-pager) etc because they leave no room for ambiguity. However, let us consider the below points before proceeding further:

- **How much confusion has the usage of** [less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less) **for Less the CSS pre-processor caused to users having questions on Less the UNIX command**? I have been very active on the [less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less) tag for atleast a year now and I have hardly seen more than 25-30 UNIX Less questions be tagged with it in the first place. That is, even before I or others have removed the tag.
- **How much percentage of questions do we get on an average for Less the UNIX command**? Based on comments and analysis by some of our fellow folks, it is very low compared to questions about Less the CSS pre-processor.
- **Is it easier to create a separate new tag for the UNIX command** ([less-pager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less-pager) **or** [less-unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less-unix)) **and re-tag questions relating to that topic**? Yes, because the no. of UNIX questions with that tag is vastly low compared to the other. Even if there is a wrong usage in future, it is easier to re-tag the UNIX questions to the new tag because the volume of such questions is less.
- **Can we do anything about the** [less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less) **to indicate that it should not be used for Less UNIX questions**? Yes, the tag wiki and excerpts are there for this purpose. While it may not be very clear for new users to understand the usage, it is easier for experienced users to guide them and re-tag the smaller volume of questions. Also, users don't have to follow a link and go visit another page to find the difference, the overlay pop-up with the excerpt can be modified to make the usage clearer. On that note, I support [this feature request of yours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256114/people-dont-read-the-tag-excerpts-because-we-dont-swat-them-into-their-faces).

Considering all the above, my suggestion is to **leave the** [less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less) **for Less CSS questions** and have a separate **new tag for Less the UNIX command** (if required). This is not a question of one bowing down to another (or) about which is more powerful than the other. Consider it more like a User ID where it doesn't matter who you are or how powerful you are, if an ID is taken by somebody else already we proceed to create a different one for us (maybe a bad analogy but you probably get the point that I am trying to make).

We have traveled too far down the alternate road to even think about going back. It is a lot of work and cost for very minimal returns.

Comment: And you noticed that I rehashed the discussion, including you guys, so there's a clear consensus over the matter. I don't feel bad about the rollback, in fact, I was more like "paving the way" rather than "actually doing the grunt work" since I needed to know exactly the extension of the problem (right now, the tag sometimes can be confused with rails, the tool, and the preprocessor). As what are the merits of my proposal, notice that even if you decide to do nothing, there are stray questions using the tag for things they are not meant to. This needs to be solved, and is part of the first...

Comment: ... operative actions within my post (the ordered list). About your worry that the tag, whichever the final name be, wouldn't have the impulse after the renaming, are covered, since the synonym system would automatically make you and whoever follows the less tag, follow the new tag, tag suggestions would be the same. I think is on everyones best interest that: the less community has a tag which is their own; the rails community don't confuse the less tag; and the less tool had some tag to ask their questions if needed, while making that each community don't step on anyones foot.

Comment: Well, there is an alternative to *just* relying on the tag-wiki: Making a synonym from [less] to something unambiguously CSSy, like [less-css]. Whether that's a good idea, seems not to have been discussed yet.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Not a bad idea. But the thing is [less] would still exist and UNIX command questions could still get tagged as [less] and may indirectly get mapped again to [less-css].

Comment: @Braiam: I am not against your ideas mate. If we were starting from scratch, I would have 100% agreed with you. My point is more on RoI and I don't see any reason for people to feel bad about this. I would have said the same even if it was the other way around (but then it is probably more easier to say that now).

Answer (score 2):

Edit: fortunately I don't need any "answer" anymore since the answers above are enough to cool down all that retagophilia.

(Not deleting this though to keep its comments).

Comment: If the synonym was the other way around, with css-less being the master, maybe.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yet, again, the synonym was [tag:less-css]. How can you guys pretend to be unbiased if you simply have no idea of what you're talking about? .

Comment: @Deduplicator Links tend to be changed with time. Language names stay.

Comment: For the question what the tag [less] means, whether it's properly css-less, less-css or lesscss is unimportant. I concede I might have inadvertantly turned them around, but how is that important? Not at all.

Comment: @Deduplicator OK, I've got your point - you just decided to push your personal vision no matter what. If it's just UNIX `less` command for *you* then it should be the same for everybody else. Period. No need to toss you pseudo rationales anymore. The idea is clear now.

Comment: Where do you get that idea? I'm just against you throwing that one out. And especially against having an answer to a (maybe clumsy) disambiguation question pretending only one of the meanings, the one you like better, existing at all.

Comment: @Deduplicator By the fact how you and five more people [there] contributed nothing under [tag:less] decided to change it judging for everybody else. Obviously `Less` language is totally less known thing in general compared to shell `less` command. But now please tell me, is there any `less`-command manual or so that has link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less? https://github.com/less/less.js (the mother repo of the Less) has it even before its own issue-traker link. So you're just going to invalidate the link many people used for *years* for a ghostly reason of disambiguation...

Comment: Yet again, just count number of corresponding questions under the tag and judge yourself. One man just came and [complained](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283550) that he personally is confused by it - and boom! to fix one man's confusion you're going to push out <put your own number here> SO members.

Comment: @seven-phases-max can we move on the discussion of "who has more questions on the tag" please? There are [users out there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256114/), that isn't intermediately obvious what a tag means, or how it should be used. You aren't loosing anything with making this change. What's so bad that makes you resist?

Comment: @Braiam and you do it again: your + 6 people opinion against hundreds (if not thousand+) asking about Less-language in [tag:less] w/o any special training. So the problem is of course in those hundreds and not in those seven, right?

Comment: Perhaps we should remove all information about the less linux command from the less tag wiki to reduce ambiguity then? Currently the tag displays "It's also a unix command to display a file."

Comment: @Mario: You are welcome to do so, just find all questions about the pager and retag them to an appropriate tag too. I'm not sure there is currently such a tag though, and that will take effort...