# How to deal with the `less` tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

Currently the [less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less) tag represents two totally irrelevant things: [GNU less](https://www.gnu.org/software/less/less.html) and [the less CSS preprocessor](http://lesscss.org/). How should we deal with this tag?

Comment: Related: [We need \[less\] no more](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293664/we-need-less-no-more)

Comment: Also [Removing the \[less\] tag from UNIX questions using the "less" command. Good thing to do?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283550/removing-the-less-tag-from-unix-questions-using-the-less-command-good-thing)

Answer (score 5):

What kind of useful programming questions could there be about the command line tool?

I'd suggest `less` should be the CSS preprocessor, and `less-command` or similar for the other one if needed.

Comment: The command line tool actually has a bunch of features...

Comment: Do any of them relate to programming?

Comment: Many possible questions. For example, it is the default underlying pager for git, which is a tool that relates programming well. It can also be used in shell scripts (programming!) for various purposes.