# Confusion between tags [df] (for Unix disk-free command) and [dataframe]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

How best to resolve the confusion between tags [df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/df) and [dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframe)?

Context:

- [df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/df) is very rare ( <2 new questions/month) and is intended for Unix disk-free command, not dataframes.

  - ~40% of questions tagged [df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/df) really intended [dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframe)
- [dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframe) is for the tabular data structure in R, Python, Spark et al.

  - The most common name for a dataframe variable is 'df'
  - 'df' is also commonly used as an abbreviation for 'dataframe', as proof see the number of hits for "the df", "this df", "your df"
  - [1.8k hits for [pandas] "the df"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpandas%5D+%22the+df%22)
  - [1.1k hits for [r] "the df"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+%22the+df%22)
- also found [one instance of 'df'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41182140/anova-cca-gives-incorrect-0-degrees-of-freedom-how-to-change-the-df) meaning '(statistical) degrees of freedom'

Suggestion:

1. everyone be aware of the need to check and retag dataframe questions that appear under [df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/df). When untagging, leave a comment for the OP so they learn.
2. add a note to [df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/df) tag description "Do not use this for 'dataframe'; use [dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframe)"

Comment: There are only 93 [tag:df] questions, so its not so hard to manually sort out the misuse.

Comment: Do we really need a tag for each command in each operative system?

Comment: Questions about the *nix command are likely to belong to http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [df+r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/df+r) is now zero.

Comment: Given that almost every 2 or 3 letter combination is some sort of Unix command, the problem is with Unix, not with the tags. And I don't think that we need tags for OS commands in the first place.

Comment: I don't understand why people would tag a question with the name of a variable used in the code. I mean, I don't see me tagging my questions with `i` and `j` whenever I nest a loop.

Comment: Anyway, I cleaned up [df+pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/df+pandas) so we're reasonably unambiguous now.

Comment: I would say this needs to be formally made into a burninate for [df]. 60 left, 52 open right now

Comment: @MrLister: when talking about dataframes, 'df' is also a common abbreviation e.g. "What are the first 5 columns of your df?" As such, the search-results for plaintext 'df' will be swamped by dataframe, hence my point about what tag to use for Linux/shell memory reporting if we burninate [tag:df]. Also, thanks for the cleanup work.

Answer (score 22):

How about we just get rid of [df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/df)?

If it's reserved for *nix's `df` command, then there's no point in its existence. It's currently causing more problems than it solves. No one here is going to be searching for questions related to it, so it's not serving the purpose of tags. And for some reason people are constantly confusing it with the tag relating to data frames.

If the tag continues to exist, it should be removed from *nix `df`-related questions and aliased to [dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframe). But unless the term `df` has some particular significance in R or some other language that has the concept, it should simply be removed and allowed to go away.

Comment: `df` is just an extremely common variable name used to refer to dataframes in R and Python example code, so it really doesn't have any more special significance than `foo` and `bar`. I think the tag can go.

Comment: We may create [tag:df-command] for related questions.

Answer (score 11):

I also support just removing the tag but this was too long for a comment so...To use the second reason of [this answer on why burnate a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250933/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work/250934#250934):

> When a tag has a clearly defined meaning, but is still misused often.

`df` has a very clear meaning but my quick count of the last 30 questions (i.e. recent usage verse all usage) shows it was used for [dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframe) half the time (16/30 to be exact). So it is being misused fairly often: showing we either need to remove it or rename it to avoid misnaming. The reasons I support removal:

1. `df` is not used as an official synonym for any of the major languages using dataframes:

Though `df` is used in several documentations as the name for the object which contains the dataframes. [Python](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) notably but also a known C#/F# [library which emulates dataframes](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/csharpframe.html) - note [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) docs tend to use `d` but many tutorials use `df` while [matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab) uses `T`. There [has already been an answer to dataframe vs. data.frame](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319591/4667934) and adding `df` as a synonym is not needed.

2. `df` is not a programming term, method, or utility

Now [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) is a language so we need to look at how the [df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/df) tag is being used. As there is [some disagreement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283550/removing-the-less-tag-from-unix-questions-using-the-less-command-good-thing/293677#293677) on whether only being a unix command is enough reason to be burnated - it bears seeing if this command is used with programming enough to be justified.

Two of the highest rated questions on df, [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962041/how-to-get-df-linux-command-output-always-in-gb/16962064) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479276/how-to-find-out-the-free-disk-space-for-a-given-path-on-a-linux-shell/479280), have already been closed as off-topic due to being about general software and hardware. Looking through most of the other ones I found that they seem to either [follow the same pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703621/get-free-disk-space-with-df-to-just-display-free-space-in-kb) (just how do I use this command and maybe redirect the output) or would [not be hurt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37385235/how-to-use-parameter-in-conf-file-for-disk-usage) by removing the [df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/df) tag or changing to [diskspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/diskspace).

TLDR;

"df" is not a term used for dataframes and has a fairly regular percentage of misuse when questions are tagged. The questions it generates when used correctly should either be closed, migrated, or are not harmed by removing the tag (or changing to a more general tag such as [diskspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/diskspace)). So unless it has enough followers to justify changing its name to `df-unix` or `df-command` it is not helping the site and should be removed.

Comment: I agree with you and thanks for all the research. Just one thing: The most common name for a dataframe variable in both Python/pandas and R is 'df'

Comment: Assuming we were to delete [tag:df] for the df-command, what tag would you then use? [tag:linux]/[tag:shell]/[tag:bash] seem too broad. There are quite a few disk-usage tools across OSes. I'm not going to suggest anything though.

Comment: @smci I wouldn't suggest any replacement, the questions I looked at mostly could have been migrated or otherwise closed so no replacement needed on SO for most part. A few may have worked with a memory, disk tag, or just by dropping the [tag:df] but I mean only 1 or 2 and hopefully people who use those tags would edit them.

Comment: @smci: `df` doesn't need a tag. Questions here asking about it are either asking about text processing in general (because output can vary across different `df`s), or are off topic here and should rather be on one of the *nix sites or on SU.

Comment: If you mean "what do I replace `df` with when referring to a dataframe" - then use [tag:dataframe]. df is just a common variable name and not really worth a tag or synonym.

Comment: @cHao: yeah I saw your answer above, and yes the subset of questions here about df-command which are on-topic on SO are about text-processing its output.

Comment: @JGreenwell: no I asked what tag would we replace [tag:df] as used for the df-command (the Unix disk-free tool), what tag would we then use? As I said above  linux/shell/bash seem way too broad. There are quite a few disk-usage tools across OSes. I'm not going to suggest anything personally but what do you all suggest? Seems like people think we just use various different OS/shell tags.

Comment: ***If*** it is created, and I still say just drop the tag, I would suggest [tag:df-command] @smci. Just avoid the OS issues Linux vs Unix vs Mac OS  and if MS ever aliases it with `get-psdrive` or something.

Comment: @JGreenwell: no, almost everyone here thinks [tag:df-command] is unneeded. And as I said, plaintext searches will be swamped with dataframe hits. So the question remains, what tag (if any) would you use to replace [tag:df]? There are several other Unix disk-reporting command-line tools too - is there a need for [tag:linux-disk-reporting] that would cover these?

Comment: what question? I would not replace it, with anything, if someone really, really wants to replace it they will put up something saying so and give their reasons - I offered two alternative if those people appear. But like all the answers and comments here I think we should just drop it - no repacement.